# Can an adverb modify a noun?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, nouns, adverbs, noun-phrases

Is it right to say:

> the scientifically literate?

The reason I ask is that "The literate" is a noun. And the adverb *scientifically* modifies it. But as far as I know, adverbs cannot modifies noun. Is this rule wrong, or is this phrase ungrammatical?

Comment: "Literate" is not a noun but an adjective in a 'fused' modifier-head construction where "literate" is understood as "literate people", i.e. the adjective "literate" serves as modifier and head at the same time in the noun phrase. Thus the adverb "scientifically" is modifying an adjective, not a noun.

Comment: You asked about adverbs modifying nouns. The answer is generally no, but it is possible, as in "A shortage of timber internationally led to a rise in prices", where the adverb "internationally" is modifying the noun "shortage". There are constraints, though, for example adverbial modifiers are restricted to post-head position.

Comment: @BillJ Isn’t that just a sentence-adverb of the same kind as found in sentence-initial position like “Internationally, the shortage of timber led to a rise in prices”? Or does that raise the question of whether *internationally* applies only to the rise or only to the shortage, rather than to the entire sentence?

Comment: @tchrist That is a different construction altogether,  where "internationally" is a modifier (or supplement) in clause structure.  In my example, "internationally" is a dependent in NP structure where it is post-modifying the noun "shortage". Another example would be "Industrial action resulted in the withdrawal indefinitely of the vehicular ferry service", where the adverb "indefinitely" is postmodifying the noun "withdrawal".

Comment: Hello, Clair. You have perhaps read somewhere that _poor_ in 'the poor are always with us' and similar constructions is a noun. You need to post a link to this. But it's almost certain that the reference work you cite won't be as highly regarded as the one @Bill is quoting from, _The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language_.

Answer (score 7):

The phrase *the literate* is what is known as a fused Modifier-head noun phrase (*fused Modifier-head NP*, for short).

This noun phrase has an elipted noun which, although missing, is understandable from the context. The head word in this noun phrase is the word *literate*. Althought is the Head of the noun phrase, it is also understood as a Modifier of the missing word.

If we wanted to we could model the noun phrase like this:

- The literate [<s>people</s>]

Here it is easy to see that the word *literate* is an adjective even though it is Head of the noun phrase. If we want to modify this adjective—in other words, we want to say that the people are literate in a scientific way, that they are literate about science—then we need an adverb, not another adjective:

- the scientifically literate [<s>people</s>]
- *the scientific literate [<s>people</s>] (ungrammatical with this meaning)
- the emotionally literate [<s>people</s>]
- the emotion literate [<s>people</s>] (ungrammatical)

---

The Original Poster asks if we can modify nouns with adverbs. The answer to this question was previously thought to be "no". However, in the past decade or so research by John Payne, on occasion in collaboration with Huddleston and Pullum, has shown that adverbs *can*, in fact modify nouns. However, they can only post-modify them (they must appear after the noun they are modifying). There are other types of restriction too. Here's an example with the noun *people* and the adverb *globally*:

- People globally are becoming concerned with what is happening to their local environment.

Here is a link to an important paper by Payne, Huddleston and Pullum where they show that adverbs do in fact sometimes post-modify nouns:

- [The distribution and category status of adjectives and adverbs. (Payne, Huddleston and Pullum. 2010)](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/PaynHuddPull.pdf)

Comment: But here it is not easy to see that _poor_ is an adjective rather than a noun: _the unfortunate poor_. As usual, there has to be a decision on whether to lump or split, and if it is decided to lump, how. (Not that I can think of a better approach than H & P's here).

Comment: There is  nothing ungrammatical about *the scientific literate*. It just means something different from *the scientifically literate* (which is the meaning people usually want).. Consider *the righteous dead* (adjective) and *the righteously dead* (adverb). They also mean different things, and here the adjective is what you usually want.

Comment: +1, but a tad 'heavy', A. I hope the OP (a non-native speaker, I suspect) understands all this!

Comment: @PeterShor, Edwin Yes *the righteous poor* etc are all ok. The difference is what is being modified. In the Original Poster's case it is the adjective (ie the Modifier part of the fused Modifier Head). In the other cases mentioned it is the elipted noun bit of the NP. So in OP's case the people are literate in a scientific way, but in EA's it is the people who are both righteous and poor. Same goes for the scientific literate [i.e.*scientific, literate (people)*.] Notice that if you put the NP back in in your cases, you'd need a comma between the two adjectives. Let me think/modify somewhat.

Comment: Hi @Bill. I tend to opt for clear and easy for the uninitiated on  ELL and treat the OP's here as a bit more savy. But point taken. I might rewrite, if I get some time. But, I aslo think Clair might have already got the lighter version from your helpful comments!

Comment: It's perfectly fine now.

Comment: Is there any functional distinction between fused modifier-head noun phrases and zero derivation of substantives from modifiers such as we see in  the famous line *“We few, we **happy few**, we band of brothers”* from Shakespeare’s St Crispin’s Day Speech? If so, what is that difference? Both seem to posit an elision of some unstated substantive to allow the modifier (here *few*, a quantifier or determiner) to be raised into a full substantive (perhaps a pronoun even?) so that it might then itself take a noun modifier in its own right: the adjective *happy*.

Comment: @tchrist Are you saying that the CGEL approach may not be the only valid one? // It boils down to preferred analysis. If a word in a construction passes 51% of our tests for an adjective, it's an adjective. The fact that it only passes 45% of OGEL's tests we'll gloss over. Or devise some more tests to show that our testing is obviously preferable to OGEL's. (OGEL an invention.)

Comment: The emotional literate? (perhaps odd, but not unacceptable)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Perhaps a contrastive adj/adv example is *the recent dead* versus *the recently dead*.

Comment: @tchrist Good example; 'recent dead' and 'recently dead' are strongly synonymous: a mere connotational change in emphasis from the deceased towards the actual deaths. This isn't the case with 'scientific literate' and 'scientifically literate', the 'intolerable poor' and the 'intolerably poor'. I wonder if the semantics plays a large part here? For these adverbs, temporal / domain / condition-appraising.