# What are time words doing when they occur after a noun?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Examples:

- People **these days** have it easy.
- People **back then** didn't know about germs.
- The news **today** makes up for the news **yesterday**.
- The meeting **Monday** will complete the agenda from the meeting **Friday**.

In some cases it can be parsed as an adverb modifying the verb or whole sentence, but not always. And it often seems very tightly tied to the noun.

Since the times can usually be moved into a prepositional phrase (usually of/from), my best guess is a noun adjunct, but noun adjuncts that occur *after* the noun are supposed to be extremely rare (the only examples I've seen were all names).

I found [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/508289/police-described-his-condition-today-as-serious-but-stable) but the only answers that make sense are downvoted.

Comment: How is "the news recently" different grammatically from "the news today" (for example)?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/what-exactly-is-an-adverb?r=SearchResults

Comment: @Laurel That sounds like an error to me (use "recent news"), unless the adverb is modifying the verb or the whole sentence (in which case it can be moved, but some of my examples can't). If it is allowed I could analyze it as "the news [that we have heard] recently" but that seems a lot to elide ...

Comment: @user405662 I'm aware that "adverb" is a strange category, but I still don't see any examples of adverbs modifying nouns there. Am I missing something in particular?

Comment: No: they are not rare. They are all temporal post-head **modifiers**. "These days" is an NP modifying "people"; "back then" is a PP modifying "people"; "today" is an NP modifying "news", and "Monday / Friday" are NPs modifying "meeting".

Comment: To me they are elided phrases. For example "People back then" is a shortened form of "People _who lived_ back then": "The news today" is short for "The news that _came out_ today" and so on. Colloquial English uses elidation a lot.

Comment: @BoldBen I wouldn't go along with what you say. There's no reason to say they are reduced clauses. NPs (typically demoting properties such as as age, time and date etc.) can certainly post modify nouns. And PPs even more freely so. Your suggestions are simply paraphrases, not syntactic analyses.

Comment: @BoldBen In the first two examples, "these days" and "back then" are adverbs that modify the clauses. This can be seen by the fact that they can be moved to the start or end of the sentence (set off from the main clause by a comma), with no change of meaning.

Comment: @BillJ Maybe I'm being a bit thick but I don't see how 'back then' is a noun phrase. Adjectival phrase certainly but I don't see it as a noun phrase

Comment: @Rosie F How are they _adverbs_? I don't see what verbs they are modifying. I'd accept _adjectives_ modifying 'people' but I don't see them as adverbs.

Comment: @BoldBen Not all adverbs modify verbs. Some modify adjectives; some modify other adverbs; some modify clauses.

Comment: All: Please write an answer, particularly if your view differs from that held by others. The question is obviously non-trivial.

Comment: @BoldBen I actually said it's a PP.

Comment: @RosieF "days" is a noun, so "these days" is an NP. "Then" (in modern grammar) is a preposition, so "back then" is a PP. All the phrases in bold are modifiers in NP structure, not in clause structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [1] [*People **these days***] *have it easy.*
>
> [2] [*People **back then***] *didn't know about germs.*
>
> [3] [*The news **today***] *makes up for the news yesterday*.
>
> [4] [*The meeting **Monday***] *will complete the agenda from* [*the meeting **Friday***].

The elements in bold are all temporal post-modifiers in NP structure.

In [1], [3] and [4] they are NPs modifying respectively "people", "news, "Monday" and "meeting". In [2] it's a PP modifying "people".

Comment: I don't see how "back then" can be a prepositional phrase. I see "back" as an adjective modifying the noun "then"; "people then" has the same meaning.

Comment: @o11c modern grammar classifies the "back" in "back then" as a preposition. It has a different sense to the "back" found in, for example "back door". In the temporal expression "back then", the prep "then" occurs as complement of "back", thus "back then" is analysed as a PP. [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/back)